# Microsoft O365 REST Graph API does not get all mails

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I get the mails from the code below after getting the security token. My problem is that in my test account, there are 22 mails (in the inbox) and the returned JSON contains only the first 10 emails.

```
var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

My get is the following code:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

I checked the resulting JSON and I can see the first 10 emails correctly.

What do I need to do to get all emails? (i.e. get the next 10, next 10... until I have all emails?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 is the default page size, so this is expected. You can expand the page size using `$top` up to 50. After that you need to request subsequent pages. There should be an `@odata.nextLink` included in the response which contains a URL to get the next page.